# High res images in iOS

Tags: ios

When i create a `UIColor` like this:

```
UIColor* backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"LoginBG.png"]];
```

On Retina displays it must take LoginBG@2x.png and on non-retina displays, it must automatically take LoginBG.png.

What if I dont add LoginBG.png into my bundle. Will iOS use the 2x version all the time on all the devices? Do I need to bundle both normal image and @2x image all the time for all images I use in my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What if I dont add LoginBG.png into my bundle. Will iOS use the 2x version all the time on all the devices?

As per my experience: it will. And thus old devices will be wasting percious RAM.

> Do I need to bundle both normal image and @2x image all the time for all images I use in my app?

Technically you don't **have to,** but I promise I won't buy any of your apps if you don't.